# Can I set SMTP settings in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I usually put my SMTP parameters for ASP.NET applications in the `<mailsettings>` element under `<system.net>` in web.config.

Is there a way to configure these at the Azure portal under Application Settings or somewhere, or do I have to manage by editing web.config?

I do not mean reading from `appSetting` keys and then stuffing them into the respective properites of `System.Net.Mail` objects. I want the parameters, example host, port, credentials, sender, etc, to be automatically filled from the configuration file (`<mailSettings>` element) when `SmtpClient` is instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not mean reading from `appSetting` keys and then stuffing them into the respective properites of `System.Net.Mail` objects. I want the parameters, example host, port, credentials, sender, etc, to be automatically filled from the configuration file when `SmtpClient` is instantiated.

***No, you cannot.***

There is an alternate solution, however. Have a look at the App Service [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure). (Any setting that's in there *overrides* the setting with the same name in the web.config.)

Since you're using the auto-config stuff of the `mailSettings` element, you're going to have to change your code to not rely on the automatic configuration. Read the settings yourself and apply them to your `SmpClient`.

You could create a custom `SmtpClient` that will be built using application settings:

```
var smtpServerHost = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SmtpServerHost");
var smtpServerPort = int.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SmtpServerPort"));
var smtpServerUserName = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SmtpServerUserName");
var smtpServerPassword = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SmtpServerPassword");

var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServerHost, smtpServerPort);
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpServerUserName, smtpServerPassword);
```

(inspired on this post: [How to set mailSettings from Azure App Service - Application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828659/how-to-set-mailsettings-from-azure-app-service-application-settings)
)

Comment: I can't find a section for the setting of  `<mailSettings>` elements. Please see my elaboration of the question.

Comment: So the answer should be "No", as in your second paragraph: "not relying on the automatic configuration". But the first two words in the answer, "You can", is misleading. Your code sample is exactly what I was wishing to avoid. My code is always simply `new SmtpClient().Send(msg);` - no manual setting of host, port, credentials, etc.